# Interpolating a complex-valued boundary function inside a circular disk with the Cauchy Intergral?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have heard that the [Cauchy integration formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cauchy-integral-formula/) can be used to interpolate complex-valued functions along a closed boundary of a disk to points inside the disk. For my current project, this sounds rather valuable, so I attempted to give this a shot. Unfortunately, my experiments were not very successful so far, and I am not certain what is going wrong. Some degree of interpolation is certainly going on, but the results do not seem to be correct along the boundaries. Here is what my code returns:

[image]

Here is my initial code example:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

# This is the interpolation function, which takes as input a position on the 
# boundary in radians (x), a complex evaluation point (eval_point), and the 
# function which returns the boundary condition
def f(x,eval_point,itp):
    
    # What is the complex coordinate of this point on the boundary?
    zi  = np.cos(x) + 1j*np.sin(x)
    
    # Get the boundary condition value
    fz  = itp(x)
    
    return fz/(zi-eval_point)

# Complex quadrature for integration, adapted from 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325919/using-scipy-quad-with-i%ce%b5-trick-bad-results
def cquad(func, a, b, **kwargs):
    real_integral = scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: np.real(func(x, **kwargs)), a, b, limit=200)
    imag_integral = scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: np.imag(func(x, **kwargs)), a, b, limit=200)
    return (real_integral[0] + 1j*imag_integral[0], real_integral[1:], imag_integral[1:])

# Define the interpolation function for the boundary values
itp     = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(
    x   = [0,np.pi/2,np.pi,1.5*np.pi,2*np.pi],
    y   = [0+0j,0+1j,1+1j,1+0j,0+0j])

# Get some evaluation points
X,Y     = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,51),
                      np.linspace(-1,1,51))
XY      = X+1j*Y
x       = np.ndarray.flatten(XY)

# Throw away all points outside the unit disk; avoid evaluting at radius 1 to
# dodge singularities
x       = x[np.where(np.abs(x) <= 0.99)]

# Calculate the result for each evaluation point
res     = []
for val in x:

    res.append(cquad(
        func    = f,
        a       = 0,
        b       = 2*np.pi,
        eval_point  = val,
        itp     = itp)[0]/(2*np.pi*1j))

# Convert the results into an array
res     = np.asarray(res)

# Plot the real part of the results
plt.tricontour(
    np.real(x),
    np.imag(x),
    np.real(res),
    cmap = 'jet')
plt.colorbar(label='real part')

# Plot the imaginary part of the results
plt.tricontour(
    np.real(x),
    np.imag(x),
    np.imag(res),
    cmap = 'Greys')
plt.colorbar(label='imaginary part')
```

Does anybody have an idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an easy approximation of that function by employing the FFT. The inverse FFT can be interpreted as polynomial evaluation at the corresponding points on the unit circle, so that the polynomial in total is an approximation of the Cauchy-formula

```
c = np.fft.fft(itp(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,401)[:-1]))
c=c[::-1]/len(c)
np.polyval(c,[1,1j,-1,-1j])
```

returns

```
[5.55111512e-17+5.55111512e-17j, 5.55111512e-17+1.00000000e+00j,
1.00000000e+00+1.00000000e+00j, 1.00000000e+00+5.55111512e-17j]
```

these are the values that were expected.

```
X,Y     = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,151),
                      np.linspace(-1,1,151))
Z      = (X+1j*Y).flatten()
Z       = Z[np.where(np.abs(Z) <= 0.99)]
W = np.polyval(c,Z)
# Plot the real part of the results
plt.tricontour( Z.real, Z.imag, W.real, cmap = 'jet')
plt.colorbar(label='real part')

# Plot the imaginary part of the results
plt.tricontour( Z.real, Z.imag, W.imag, cmap = 'Greys')
plt.colorbar(label='imaginary part')
plt.tight_layout(); plt.show()
```

This then gives the picture

[image: contour plot]

The dominant terms of the polynomial are

```
(1+1j)*(0.500000 - 0.045040*z^3 - 0.008279*z^7 
          - 0.005012*z^391 - 0.016220*z^395 - 0.405293*z^399)
```

As far as I could see, the leading degree 3 after the constant term is constant under refinement of the sampling sequence.